# dynamic modals when i click on dynamic buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic, modal-dialog

I, i'm new here so i don't really know mutch, but i need to figure out this thing:
i have a php page with some dynamic buttons.

I want this dynamic buttons to open a modal with dynamic content but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

As you can see from my test site [here](http://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/home-configurator/mono/dimensioni.php?style=Smart), if you click on the first button it will display the modal with correct content, but if you click on the second button (dinamically generatated) it doesn't display anyting.

here's my code, but it's more simple to understand trough the previous link;

```js
<!------------------------------------------- ATTIVAZIONE MODAL--------------------------------->

    <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("<?php echo $mq_solarium; ?>");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("chiudi_dimensione")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "flex";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<!-------------------------------------------FINE ATTIVAZIONE MODAL--------------------------------->
```

```css
.plan-wrapper {

    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-wrapper dimensioni">
<?php
    //estraggo i valori per smart
    $query=mysqli_query($con, " SELECT * FROM appartamenti INNER JOIN moduli ON appartamenti.id_planimetria = moduli.id_planimetria  WHERE taglio='monolocale' AND visibile='1' "); 

?>

     
               
  <div id="myBtn"class="plan-wrapper">click me</div>

  <div style="background-color:DodgerBlue;" id="myModal" class="lightbox_wrapper_dimensione">
    <div id="close" class="chiudi_dimensione">X(close)</div>
    some variables from php
  </div>
</div>
 
 <?php       
}
    }
    else {
    // redirect user to another page
    header( "Location: ../index.php" ); die;
        }
?> 
 
 <!------------------------------------------- CHIUSURA PHP--------------------------------->   
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in `getElementById()` it can triger only 1 id at the time you should change this to some another logic of clicking and geting the modal data or foreach this script as well as data and generate different id values 
So you can have only 1 `myBtn` id on whole page you can make something like `myBtn1`,`myBtn2`, `myBtn3` ... 
or
`<div class='myBtn' data-id='1'>...content...</div>`
and use this `data-id` to access modal you need

For example to show modal using jquery you can do like this
first change the id to class in each button and add `data-id='number_of_item'` numbers should be different the same thing you should do with modals you should generate them with `id='myModal_number_of_item'` in the same foreach! After you can use code bellow to open modal with query its easier for me but you can make it with pure javascript.

```
$('.myBtn').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#myModal_'+id).show();
})
```

Comment: Hi @olexander, I Have understand the problem. Can you suggest me what logic I have to use please? i'm really new to this and my boss gave me this complex job to do... another question: so i have to generate dynamic data-id?

Comment: you should have unique values for each button for accessing correct modal window so yes it should be generated dynamically.

Comment: @Stefano Zanetti you did it by yourself i just wanted to point you in the right direction, have fun there :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In this case, you have `id="myBtn"` in multiple areas. The ID is designed to be unique in an entire document.
So, when you have `document.getElementById("myBtn")` and the event to that object, it will work only for the very first element as you experienced before.

The solution is either to have different unique IDs or just use className.

If you want with Vanilla Javascript this is the solution:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("<?php echo $mq_solarium; ?>");
for( let i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++){
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       modal.style.display = "flex";
    } );
}
```

Or using Jquery

```
$(".<?php echo $mq_solarium; ?>").click(function(){
    modal.style.display = "flex";
});
```

But make sure you will replace `id="myBtn"` to `class="myBtn"`

Comment: Hi Harry, I think i'm understanding now.
Now, if you check my link, you will see that the modals are all with differents and unique IDs, but now any of the buttons (i've changed the entire dynamic area to be the button) doesn't work.. i'm getting mad... :(

Comment: You have your code before jquery is defined. so instead of `$(".myBtn").click(function(){
    modal.style.display = "flex";
});` use `$(document).ready(function(){$(".myBtn").click(function(){
    modal.style.display = "flex";
});});` 
p.s
Please  make sure that your jquery is included before your code

Comment: just put this line `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` somewhere at the top of you another scripts

Comment: Thank you! it worked!
But i've another problem... when I click it appear the modal, but not with the correct information.. it display always the contents of the last button (you can see it if you compare the "price".. Can you help me for the last time? Thank you :(

Comment: @Stefano Zanetti for this you should specify modal you are trying to access, try using my code with `data-id` and take this `id` from the table or provide more php code how are you getting data after query

Comment: @StefanoZanetti I can see that you are using `id="myModal_"` and adding a number, that numbers look like IDs from your database. Try to add numbers from 0 and increase one by one. You should get ids like myModal_0, myModal_1, myModal_2 etc. Then in jquery, you can modify a little bit your click function. `$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".myBtn").each(function(index){
  $(this).click(function(){ 
   $("#myModal_"+index).css("display","flex"); 
  });
 });
});`  If you assign clicks like that it will match server generated IDs and you will get desired result.